# Add/ remove method working in onCreate but not in onPageSelected

Tags: android

i have two viewpager i am removing current page of one viewpager from second pager. and add removed page again when swipe to next position. same process for second viewpager. Problem is add and remove method work fine if i use them in onCreate but not working in onPageSelected. and other problem is if i add any removed page on same position again it show me added page on current position of viewpager. i want page just add on that specific position but do not set on current position.
Below is my code.Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    CustomViewPager pager1,pager2;
    List<Fragment> fragments1,fragments2;
    public PagerAdapter adapter1;
    public PagerAdapter1 adapter2;
     int lostPositionRight;
     int lostPositionLeft;

   ArrayList<String> image = new ArrayList<String>() {{
         add("0");
         add("1");
         add("2");
         add("3");
         add("4");
     }};

     ArrayList<String> imageNew = new ArrayList<String>() {{
         add("0");
         add("1");
         add("2");
         add("3");
         add("4");
     }};


     ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(R.drawable.first);
        add(R.drawable.second);
        add(R.drawable.three);
        add(R.drawable.four);
        add(R.drawable.xiaomi);
    }};

     ArrayList<Integer> imagesNew = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
         add(R.drawable.first);
         add(R.drawable.second);
         add(R.drawable.three);
         add(R.drawable.four);
         add(R.drawable.xiaomi);
     }};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);

        pager1 = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
        fragments1 = getFragments1();
        adapter1 = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments1);
        pager1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        removeView1(1);
        lostPositionLeft = 1;
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

        pager2 = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager2);
        fragments2 = getFragments2();
        adapter2 = new PagerAdapter1(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments2);
        pager2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        pager2.setCurrentItem(1);
        removeView2(0);
        lostPositionRight = 0;

        pager1.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                MyImageSlider fragmntDta = (MyImageSlider)findFragmentByPosition(pager1.getCurrentItem());
                String value = fragmntDta.getTextOnTextView();
                int p = Integer.parseInt(value);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text is " +p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                addView2(lostPositionRight,lostPositionRight);
                removeView2(p);

               adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
               lostPositionRight = p;
            }
           @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        pager2.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               MyImageSlider1 fragmntDta = (MyImageSlider1)findFragmentByPosition2(pager2.getCurrentItem());
                String value1 = fragmntDta.getTextView();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text is " +value1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
               int p = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                addView1(lostPositionLeft,lostPositionLeft);
                removeView1(p);
                lostPositionLeft = p;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

     public void addView1(int index,int position)
     {
         adapter1.addView1 (index,position);
         adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     public void addView2(int index,int position)
     {
         adapter2.addView2 (index,position);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     public void removeView1 (int position)
     {
         adapter1.removeView1(pager1, position);
         adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     public void removeView2 (int position)
     {
         adapter2.removeView2(pager2, position);
         adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }



     public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;
        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

         @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

      @Override
      public int getItemPosition (Object object)
      {

          return POSITION_NONE;
      }


         public int removeView1 (ViewPager pager, int position)
         {
             pager.setAdapter (null);
             fragments.remove (position);
             pager.setAdapter (this);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             return position;
         }

             public void addView1 (int index,int position)
             {
                 fragments.add(index,MyImageSlider.newInstance(images.get(position),image.get(position)));
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
             }

     }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments1() {
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            fList.add(MyImageSlider.newInstance(images.get(i),image.get(i)));
        }
        return fList;
    }

     public static class MyImageSlider extends Fragment {
         int imageid;
         String newid;
         TextView textView;

         public static MyImageSlider newInstance(int id,String s)
         {
             MyImageSlider slider=new MyImageSlider();
             Bundle b=new Bundle();
             b.putInt("imageid", id);
             b.putString("newid", s);
             slider.setArguments(b);
             return slider;
         }
         public String getTextOnTextView(){
             return (String) textView.getText();
         }


         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             imageid=getArguments().getInt("imageid");
             newid = getArguments().getString("newid");
         }

         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftpager,container, false);
             ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
             textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
             iv.setImageResource(imageid);
             textView.setText(newid);
             return view;
         }
     }

     public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
         PagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = adapter1;
         return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + pager1.getId() + ":" +
                         fragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId(position));
     }


     public class PagerAdapter1 extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragment;

        public PagerAdapter1(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragment = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragment.get(position);
        }

       @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragment.size();
        }

      @Override
      public int getItemPosition (Object object)
      {
          return POSITION_NONE;
      }

        public int removeView2 (ViewPager pager, int position)
        {
            pager.setAdapter (null);
            fragment.remove (position);
            pager.setAdapter (this);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return position;
        }

         public void addView2 (int index,int position)
         {
             fragment.add(index,MyImageSlider1.newInstance(imagesNew.get(position),imageNew.get(position)));
             notifyDataSetChanged();

         }
    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments2() {
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesNew.size(); i++) {
            fList.add(MyImageSlider1.newInstance(imagesNew.get(i),imageNew.get(i)));

        }
        return fList;
    }

     public static class MyImageSlider1 extends Fragment {
        int imageid;
         String newid;
       public TextView textView1;

        public static MyImageSlider1 newInstance(int id,String s)
        {
            MyImageSlider1 slider=new MyImageSlider1();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putInt("imageid", id);
            b.putString("newid", s);
            slider.setArguments(b);
            return slider;
        }

         public String getTextView(){
             return (String) textView1.getText();
         }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            imageid=getArguments().getInt("imageid");
            newid = getArguments().getString("newid");

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightpager, container, false);
            ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image2);
            iv.setImageResource(imageid);
            textView1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            textView1.setText(newid);

            return view;
        }

    }
     public Fragment findFragmentByPosition2(int position) {
         PagerAdapter1 fragmentPagerAdapter2 = adapter2;
         return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag
                 ("android:switcher:" + pager2.getId() + ":" + fragmentPagerAdapter2.getItemId(position));
     }
}
```

Comment: try using FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: yuppp right its working. but now following method creating problem because its using method of FragmentPagerAdapter. what is the solution for this:     public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
         PagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = adapter1;
         return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + pager1.getId() + ":" +
                         fragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId(position));
     }

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?!  whats the problem with that ?

Comment: i want to compare images of both viewpager if one present in first viewpager it should not be in second viewpager. when i swipe to next page image that i remove should be added again in same position and current visible position should be remove from second pager.

Comment: see my edited code .... here problem is   findFragmentByPosition2(int position) is using getItemId(position) method form getting unique id of current view, which is of FragmentPagerAdaper method.  I want any alternate of this method
     }

Comment: Just want to know why you are remove page instead of that just update that frament    use this method getItem (selectedPosition) of pagerAdapter1

and just use  pagerAdapter1.notifydatasetchange()

Comment: i am making app for comparison purpose so there are two viewpagers in one activity both are containing five-five pages . both pager contain same data. i want if one image is showing in left side it should not have to show on right side thats why onpageselected i am removing fragment of right viewpager.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

But, for your desired purpose, you are going the wrong way.

Try doing this:

1. You said both view pagers are showing same thing. So there is no need too have two same list. One from each is enough.

   ```
   ArrayList<String> imageNew = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("0");
    add("1");
    add("2");
    add("3");
    add("4");
    }};


   ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
   add(R.drawable.first);
   add(R.drawable.second);
   add(R.drawable.three);
   add(R.drawable.four);
   add(R.drawable.xiaomi);
   }};
   ```
2. Define an onPageChangedListener for your view pager. So every time the page changed, you have the `index`. Just make a clone from both your lists and remove the desired index and make a new adapter and set that for the other view pager.

Comment: yes sir specially FragmentStatePagerAdapter work like magic for me . but now only problem i have is when new page is added to view-page it set added page as it current visible viewpage page. i mean its right its refresh the fragment. but i want when new page added to viewPager it should not be set as current visible page in viewpager. i google it but find nothing

Comment: Use viewpager.setcurrentitem(ANY_INDEX_YOU_WANT) after you adding page.